# pandas series mark all the rows between two values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a series ( a single col in a df) with 3 possible values:

```
Stable, Increase, Decresae
```

, and I want to mark all the areas between a Increase to the subsequent Decrease. So for the values:

```
Stable
Stable
Stable
Increase
Increase
Stable
Stable
Decrease
Stable
Increase
Stable
Decrease
```

I will get: `-,-,-,+,+,+,+,-,-,+,+,-`
What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) `True` on Increase and `False` on Decrease, then [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html). Finally map the +/- with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = df['col'].map({'Increase': True, 'Decrease': False}).ffill().fillna(False)
df['indicator'] = np.where(s, '+', '-')
```

As a one-liner:

```
df['indicator'] = np.where(df['col'].map({'Increase': True, 'Decrease': False})
                                    .ffill().fillna(False),
                           '+', '-')
```

Output:

```
         col indicator
0     Stable         -
1     Stable         -
2     Stable         -
3   Increase         +
4   Increase         +
5     Stable         +
6     Stable         +
7   Decrease         -
8     Stable         -
9   Increase         +
10    Stable         +
11  Decrease         -
```

Intermediates:

```
         col    map  ffill+fillna indicator
0     Stable    NaN         False         -
1     Stable    NaN         False         -
2     Stable    NaN         False         -
3   Increase   True          True         +
4   Increase   True          True         +
5     Stable    NaN          True         +
6     Stable    NaN          True         +
7   Decrease  False         False         -
8     Stable    NaN         False         -
9   Increase   True          True         +
10    Stable    NaN          True         +
11  Decrease  False         False         -
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```
np.where
(s.where(s.eq('Increase') | s.eq('Decrease')).ffill().eq('Increase'),
 '+', '-')
```

Output:

```
array(['-', '-', '-', '+', '+', '+', '+', '-', '-', '+', '+', '-'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to `NaN`s only `Stable` values, forward filling existing values here `Increase` and `Decrease` and compare by `Increase` for set values `0/-` in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['col'].replace({'Stable': np.nan}).ffill().eq('Increase'), '+','-')
print (df)
         col new
0     Stable   -
1     Stable   -
2     Stable   -
3   Increase   +
4   Increase   +
5     Stable   +
6     Stable   +
7   Decrease   -
8     Stable   -
9   Increase   +
10    Stable   +
11  Decrease   -
```

Intermediate:

```
print (df.assign(repl=df['col'].replace({'Stable': np.nan}),
                 ffill=df['col'].replace({'Stable': np.nan}).ffill(),
                 comp=df['col'].replace({'Stable': np.nan}).ffill().eq('Increase'),
                 out=np.where(df['col'].replace({'Stable': np.nan}).ffill().eq('Increase'), '+','-')))
         col      repl     ffill   comp out
0     Stable       NaN       NaN  False   -
1     Stable       NaN       NaN  False   -
2     Stable       NaN       NaN  False   -
3   Increase  Increase  Increase   True   +
4   Increase  Increase  Increase   True   +
5     Stable       NaN  Increase   True   +
6     Stable       NaN  Increase   True   +
7   Decrease  Decrease  Decrease  False   -
8     Stable       NaN  Decrease  False   -
9   Increase  Increase  Increase   True   +
10    Stable       NaN  Increase   True   +
11  Decrease  Decrease  Decrease  False   -
```